# ceph crushtool piping commands is not working

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ceph, crush

I am running this command inside a ceph monitor container

```
ceph osd getcrushmap | crushtool -d - | less
```

It shows me the output of the decompiled crush map. When I try with

```
ceph osd getcrushmap | crushtool -d - | crushtool -c -
```

I get an error, input file - not found

Any ideas how can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

try  with 2 steps :

```
ceph osd getcrushmap -o {compiled-crushmap-filename} && crushtool -d {compiled-crushmap-filename} -o {decompiled-crushmap-filename}
```

then check the  file  {decompiled-crushmap-filename} content is readable, if yes  - recompile with crushtool -c